# Removing Java Swing Containers dynamically (my code hangs on button press)

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am trying to implement something that I feel should be easy, but I can't make it work.
I have a Jframe, which contains 2 JPanel.
I want to have a button in one of the JPanel that on click, will remove the JPanel it is from from the JFrame. (I'm doing the proof of concept right now, there will be more JPanel in the future).

```
buttonRemove.addActionListener( (e) -> {
    buttonRemove.getParent().getParent().remove(buttonRemove.getParent());
});
```

is my ActionListener which makes the program hang. What am I understanding wrong here? What is the best practice to do what I want?

EDIT:

```
FractalBuilder extends JFrame{
    public JPanel image;
    public JPanel fonction;
    public FractalBuilder(){
       setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

       fonction = new JPanel();
       JButton buttonRemove = new JButton(Remove);
       buttonRemove.addActionListener( (e) -> {
           buttonRemove.getParent().getParent().remove(buttonRemove.getParent());
       });
       fonction.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
       GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints;
       fonction.add(buttonRemove, gbc);
       add(fonction, BORDER_LAYOUT.WEST);
       add(image, BORDER_LAYOUT.EAST);
}
```

I added the code that I feel might be relevant, but will add github link for the full source if needed.

Comment: `but will add github link for the full source if needed.` - we don't want you entire application. We want the full code that demonstrates the problem. That is post a proper [MCVE]. So in your case you need a frame with a panel with a button. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and test the code to see the behaviour that you describe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add/remove components from a panel of a visible GUI the basic logic is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

You need the revalidate() to invoke the layout manager and the repaint() to make sure all the components are repainted with the new layout.

Comment: Oh. Right, that makes sense. How do I call revalidate from the actionListener that just got removed though?
Oh, if I call a function in the JFrame with the component to remove in argument, I can do that easier. Thanks!

Comment: I showed you how. You need a reference to the parent panel. So assign your getParent().getParent() to a variable.

Comment: I don't think the calls to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` should be necessary.  The container knows to revalidate and repaint itself whenever something is added or removed.  I think it's more likely that the OP's call chain `.getParent().getParent().` wasn't working, and that just adding a reference to the parent panel was what fixed the problem.

Comment: @markspace, `The container knows to revalidate and repaint itself whenever something is added or removed.` -  no it doesn't. A Swing component will revalidate() and repaint() itself when a property of the component is changed, but a Container does not do this automatically when a component is added/removed from the Container. That is why you need to add the code manually.

Comment: @camickr I'm pretty sure I've seen that (revalidation on add/remove) in the code for the LayoutManager, but I'd have to check it out with grepcode or something.  Do you happen to have a source for "not..when a component is add/removed"?  I'm interesting in seeing if this is documented anywhere.

Comment: @camickr Link to docs for `Container.add()` : **This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy.**  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-

Comment: @camickr And ditto for `remove()` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove-java.awt.Component-  So unless I'm missing something I don't think your statement is correct.

Comment: @markspace API documentation can be misinterpreted. This is a common question (usually about adding components). My solution is based on personal experience and testing. It works the way I stated on my platform and Java version. Create your own [mcve] that demonstrates your claim.  All you need to do is create a frame using a JPanel with a FlowLayout. Add any component to the panel, then add your delete button. Then write the ActionListener to only remove the component (which won't work). Then try it again and add revalidate() (which partially works). Then try it again adding the repaint().